# How to build a spec for a waiting worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, worker

I am trying to make a spec for this call (kind of simple job):

`SomeJob.set(wait: 3.seconds).perform_later(messenger.id, EVENT)`

The spec that I currently have:

```
it 'should call an event for...' do
  expect(SomeJob).to receive(:set).with(wait: 3.seconds).and_call_original
  subject.save
end
```

And it works fine, but I also want to test that it is calling `perform_later` after 3 seconds. What is the right way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActiveJob::TestHelper` and `ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers`.

Add helper to `rails_helper.rb`.

```
  config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper
  config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
```

Add test to spec.

```
class Some < ApplicationRecord
  def hello
    SomeJob.set(wait: 3.seconds).perform_later 'Hello!'
  end
end
```

```
RSpec.describe Some, type: :model do
  it 'should start job after 3 seconds' do
    time = Time.current
    travel_to(time) do
      assertion = {
        job: SomeJob,
        args: ['Hello!'],
        at: (time + 3.seconds).to_i
      }
      assert_enqueued_with(assertion) { Some.new.hello }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!